# How get output in _thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, output, connection-pooling

i created a function with Python, for the poaching of some devices, the need for fast times or the idea of using threads. the python code I wrote function and it is very fast the peripherals respond (verified with wire shark), but now I need each thread to have the output of the function I launch to have them all in an output vector. How can I save the output of each thread I launch with this "_thread" library?

below is the code I used:

```
import _thread
import time

import atenapy

try:
   tic = time.process_time()
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5A0000005A'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2600000026'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5100000051'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2700000027'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5000000050'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'6000000060'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5200000052'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2D0000002D'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5700000057'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'5F0000005F'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5300000053'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2200000022'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5600000056'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2300000023'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5500000055'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2B0000002B'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.172',9761,'5400000054'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2C0000002C'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'0C0000000C'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2800000028'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'0D0000000D'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2900000029'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'0E0000000E'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.170',9761,'2A0000002A'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'0F0000000F'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1400000014'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1800000018'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1900000019'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1A0000001A'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1B0000001B'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1C0000001C'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1D0000001D'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1E0000001E'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'1F0000001F'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'2000000020'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.164',9761,'2100000021'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.162',9761,'0200000002'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.162',9761,'0300000003'))
   _thread.start_new_thread(atenapy.connect_PE,('192.168.2.162',9761,'0800000008'))
   toc = time.process_time()
   print("all PE time pooling = "+str(toc - tic))
except:
   print ("Error: unable to start thread")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function in a worker function that collects the result and appends to a list.  The lock is optional when appending to a list (Ref: [What kinds of global value mutation are thread safe](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm)).

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
results = []

def func(a,b):
    with lock:
        results.append(a+b)

threads = [threading.Thread(target=func,args=(a,b))
           for a in range(3) for b in range(3)]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(results)
```